# Combining stacked area chart and brushing in D3

Tags: javascript, d3.js, brush, stacked-area-chart

I'm struggling to take a stacked area chart in D3 and add [brushing](http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/1667367) features. I've managed to generate both the large (focus) and small (context) axes, and the plot looks fine to start. My problems is that the brushing features don't work at all. I've been banging my head on this for some time, to no avail, and can't figure out where the problem is. Any help would be much appreciated!

Click [here](http://mypage.iu.edu/~jlorince/debug/stackedAreaBrushing.html) to see the current state of the plot. Here's the code:

```
<!-- language: lang-js -->
<!DOCTYPE html>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<style>

body {
    font: 10px sans-serif;
}

.axis path,
.axis line {
    fill: none;
    stroke: #000;
    shape-rendering: crispEdges;
}

.tag text {
    text-anchor: end;
}

</style>
<body onLoad="updateData()">
        <div id="option" style="font-size:14px;">
        <form>
        Number of tags:<input value="5" id="nTags_select"></input>
        <input name="updateButton" 
                                 type="button" 
                                value="Update" 
                                onclick="updateData()" />
                        </form>
</div>  
<script src="http://d3js.org/d3.v3.js"></script>
<script>

var margin = {top: 10, right: 10, bottom: 100, left: 40},
    margin2 = {top: 430, right: 10, bottom: 20, left: 40},
    width = 960 - margin.left - margin.right,
    height = 500 - margin.top - margin.bottom,
    height2 = 500 - margin2.top - margin2.bottom;


var parseDate = d3.time.format("%Y-%m-%d").parse;

var x = d3.time.scale().range([0, width]),
    x2 = d3.time.scale().range([0, width]),
    y = d3.scale.linear().range([height, 0]),
    y2 = d3.scale.linear().range([height2, 0]);

var color = d3.scale.category20();

var xAxis = d3.svg.axis().scale(x).orient("bottom"),
    xAxis2 = d3.svg.axis().scale(x2).orient("bottom"),
    yAxis = d3.svg.axis().scale(y).orient("left");

var brush = d3.svg.brush()
   .x(x2)
  .on("brush", brushed);

var area = d3.svg.area()
    .interpolate("basis")
    .x(function(d) { return x(d.date); })
        .y0(function(d) { return y(d.y0); })
        .y1(function(d) { return y(d.y0 + d.y); });

var area2 = d3.svg.area()
    .interpolate("basis")
    .x(function(d) { return x2(d.date); })  
        .y0(function(d) { return y2(d.y0); })
        .y1(function(d) { return y2(d.y0 + d.y); });

var stack = d3.layout.stack()
        .values(function(d) { return d.values; });



 var oRequest = new XMLHttpRequest();
 var sURL  = "data100.tsv";
 oRequest.open("GET",sURL,false);
 oRequest.setRequestHeader("User-Agent",navigator.userAgent);
 oRequest.send(null)
 var data = oRequest.responseText;

 var data = d3.tsv.parse(data);

    data.forEach(function(d) {
        d.date = parseDate(d.date);
    });

    color.domain(d3.keys(data[0]).filter(function(key) { return key !== "date"; }));
    var allTags = stack(color.domain().map(function(name) {
        return {
            name: name,
            values: data.map(function(d) {
                return {date: d.date, y: +d[name]};
            })
        };
    }));


    function updateData(){
        var nTags = document.getElementById('nTags_select').value;
        tags=allTags.slice(0,nTags);

    x.domain(d3.extent(data, function(d) { return d.date; }));
    y.domain([0,d3.max(tags, function(d) { return d3.max(d.values, function (d) { return d.y + d.y0; }); })]);
    x2.domain(x.domain());
    y2.domain(y.domain());  

    d3.select("svg").remove();

    var svg = d3.select("body").append("svg")
        .attr("width", width + margin.left + margin.right)
        .attr("height", height + margin.top + margin.bottom)

    svg.append("defs").append("clipPath")
    .attr("id", "clip")
  .append("rect")
    .attr("width", width)
    .attr("height", height);

var focus = svg.append("g")
    .attr("transform", "translate(" + margin.left + "," + margin.top + ")");

var context = svg.append("g")
    .attr("transform", "translate(" + margin2.left + "," + margin2.top + ")");

focus.selectAll('path')
            .data(tags)
            .enter()
            .append('path')
            .attr('clip-path','url(#clip)')
            .attr("d", function(d) { return area(d.values); })
            .attr('class','focus')
            .style("fill", function(d) { return color(d.name); });

  focus.append("g")
      .attr("class", "x axis")
      .attr("transform", "translate(0," + height + ")")
      .call(xAxis);

  focus.append("g")
      .attr("class", "y axis")
      .call(yAxis);


context.selectAll('path')
            .data(tags)
            .enter()
            .append('path')
            .attr('class','context')
            .attr("d", function(d) { return area2(d.values); })
            .style("fill", function(d) { return color(d.name); });


  context.append("g")
      .attr("class", "x axis")
      .attr("transform", "translate(0," + height2 + ")")
      .call(xAxis2);

  context.append("g")
      .attr("class", "x brush")
      .call(brush)
    .selectAll("rect")
      .attr("y", -6)
      .attr("height", height2 + 7);


  focus.append("text")
            .datum(function(d) { return {name: d.name, value: d.values[d.values.length - 1]}; })
            .attr("transform", function(d) { return "translate(" + x(d.value.date) + "," + y(d.value.y0 + d.value.y / 2) + ")"; })
            .attr("x", -6)
            .attr("dy", "-.35em")
            .text(function(d) { return d.name; });

};




function brushed() {
  x.domain(brush.empty() ? x2.domain() : brush.extent());
  focus.selectAll("path.focus").attr("d", area);
  focus.select(".x.axis").call(xAxis);
}

</script>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In Mike's original code, he chose the name focus for his svg element which is unfortunate - it  [already exists in the dom](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/Mozilla_event_reference/focus), and might be confusing matters.

In any case, the problem here is primarily one of scope.

Mike defines `focus` outside the scope of getting the data, thus putting it into the global scope. Therefore, it's available to the `brushed()` function.

The first step I would take would be to move the definition of the `focus` var outside of the updateData() function.

However, there are a few other problems:

- You should be using d3.tsv with an anonymous function to get the data. It will make things much simpler.
- In the brushed function, you need to use an anonymous function and pass the area function d.values, rather than just d. You did this in the updateData function, but not in brushed. i.e.:

  ```
  function brushed() {   
      x.domain(brush.empty() ? x2.domain() : brush.extent());
      focus.selectAll("path.focus").attr("d", function(d){return area(d.values)});
      focus.select(".x.axis").call(xAxis);
  }
  ```

I have a rough version of your chart with the brushing working here: http://jsfiddle.net/zQ2EF/ but, I would go over Mike's example with careful attention to where things are defined, and which scope they are in - it will help you understand where the problem lies!

Comment: Thanks! This is quite helpful. I originally modeled the code after Mike's example, but this was giving me problems when trying to add the update functionality. I ended up setting things as they were so I could load the data once, and then just select the subset to plot using the form element, clear the plot, and redraw. It was unclear how to do this with usual "d3.tsv("blah.tsv", function(error, data) { .... };" format. Would you place the d3.tsv function inside or outside the "updateData()" function? Thanks again.

Comment: ok, found it at your iu.edu website: http://mypage.iu.edu/~jlorince/projects/tagging/tagExplorer.html

Comment: Sorry for the delay - was just about to post that link. The code is a bit ugly, and there are certainly many things I should have done differently, but at least it's working now.